# Dotnet Core 2.0.3 Migration | Encoding unable to translate bytes [8B]

Tags: azure, .net-core, httpclient, azure-web-app-service

Im not sure if this should just go direct to the github but I thought id check here first if anyone has encountered this issue before.

I recently have upgraded one of my apps to use dot net 2.0.3 From 1.1.4.

Everything works fine locally but when I deploy to my app service in azure I get the following exception.

```
System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [8B] at index 1 from specified code page to Unicode.
```

The code that calls it is a httpclient that talks between the apps.

```
public async Task<T1> Get<T1>(string url, Dictionary<string, string> urlParameters = null) where T1 : DefaultResponse, new()
{
    var authToken = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["authToken"];
    using (var client = new HttpClient().AcceptJson().Acceptgzip().AddAuthToken(authToken))
    {
        var apiResponse = await client.GetAsync(CreateRequest(url, urlParameters));

        T1 output;
        if (apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            output = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<T1>();
            //output.Succeeded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            output = new T1();
            var errorData = GlobalNonSuccessResponseHandler.Handle(apiResponse);
            output.Succeeded = false;
            output.Messages.Add(errorData);
        }
        return output;
    }
}

public static HttpClient AcceptJson(this HttpClient client)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return client;
}

public static HttpClient Acceptgzip(this HttpClient client)
{
    // Commenting this out fixes the issue.
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("gzip"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("deflate"));
    return client;
}

public static HttpClient AddAuthToken(this HttpClient client, string authToken)
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
    return client;
}
```

Im a bit stumped as to whats going on.

So I have 2 apps which we call client and server from now on.

Client uses the above code to talk to the server.

Locally this is fine on azure not so, this all worked fine before upgrading.

So I setup the client locally to talk to the server on azure I was able to replicate the issue.

I had a look at the response in fiddler and it is able to correctly decode it.

If anyone has any idea where I should look and has seen it before any info would be great :D.

**UPDATE 1**

So after some more digging I decided to remove gzip and then everything started working.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("gzip"));
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I have added a github issue to try shed some more light on this https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25705

Answer (score 2):

8B can be a second byte of multi-byte UTF8 character. The DecoderFallbackException tells that you’re interpreting the data as some other encoding. Probably Latin-1 which [doesn’t have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) 8B character.

In fiddler, you should look at the `content-type` HTTP header in the response. If it says `application/json` or `application/json; charset=utf-8`, it’s probably a bug in .NET, because even without `charset=utf-8` RFC 4627 says the default encoding is already UTF-8.

If it says something else, I would try changing the server so it sends the correct content-type header in the response.

Comment: The Content-Type is application/json; charset=utf-8 in fiddle.
I guess ill post on the the dotnet githubs